zfs, possibly bad performance
I am looking to confirm if this behaviour is normal as I got a new server and I am testing some SQL queries and they seem to be slightly slower than on the old machine. This is freebsd 14.1
When I copy a bunch of large files between 2 folders on the same disk, I am getting the following output from zpool iostat
              capacity     operations     bandwidth
pool        alloc   free   read  write   read  write
----------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
zroot       90.6G   797G      8     61   272K  1.86M
zroot       90.6G   797G      0      0      0      0
zroot       90.6G   797G      0      0      0      0
zroot       90.6G   797G      0    125      0  1.12M
zroot       90.6G   797G      0      0      0      0
zroot       90.6G   797G      0      0      0      0
zroot       90.6G   797G      0      0      0      0
zroot       90.6G   797G      0    138      0  2.23M
zroot       90.6G   797G  2.05K      0   138M      0
zroot       90.6G   797G  1.66K      0   122M      0
zroot       90.6G   797G  1.80K  1.22K  98.4M  91.7M
zroot       91.0G   797G  3.75K  3.37K   189M   249M
zroot       91.0G   797G  3.19K  2.46K   142M   240M
zroot       91.2G   797G  2.53K    593   108M  49.9M
zroot       91.2G   797G  1.84K      0  86.9M      0
zroot       91.2G   797G  3.77K  2.81K   181M   268M
zroot       91.2G   797G  2.20K      0  98.5M      0
zroot       91.5G   797G  3.27K  3.02K   159M   295M
zroot       91.5G   797G  2.63K      0   144M      0
zroot       91.4G   797G  3.52K  3.46K   204M   326M
zroot       91.4G   797G  2.26K      0   128M      0
zroot       91.4G   797G  1.85K  1.29K   112M   117M
zroot       91.4G   797G  2.67K  2.75K   118M   244M
zroot       91.4G   797G  1.43K      0  51.6M      0
zroot       91.4G   797G  1.84K    873  74.8M  84.0M
zroot       91.3G   797G  2.99K  1.86K   161M   188M
zroot       91.3G   797G  1.40K      0  70.7M      0
zroot       91.3G   797G  1.81K  1.03K  79.6M  97.5M
zroot       91.6G   796G  2.84K  2.22K   137M   212M
zroot       91.6G   796G  1.50K      0  81.5M      0
zroot       91.6G   796G  1.42K      0  73.9M      0
zroot       91.5G   797G  2.94K  3.28K   159M   315M
zroot       91.5G   797G  2.36K      0   121M      0
zroot       91.5G   797G  3.80K  3.58K   173M   331M
zroot       91.5G   797G  2.84K      0   123M      0
zroot       91.3G   797G  2.74K  2.84K   175M   275M
zroot       91.3G   797G  2.35K      0   108M      0
zroot       91.3G   797G  3.86K  3.51K   170M   326M
zroot       91.3G   797G  2.23K      0  93.8M      0
zroot       91.5G   796G  3.52K  2.74K   171M   274M
zroot       91.5G   796G  1.93K      0   106M      0
zroot       91.5G   796G  1.90K      0   116M      0
zroot       91.5G   797G  2.85K  3.90K   188M   347M
zroot       91.5G   797G  1.50K      0  90.2M      0
zroot       91.5G   797G  1.97K      0   131M      0
zroot       91.5G   796G  3.26K  4.83K   215M   405M
zroot       91.5G   796G  2.53K      0   161M      0
zroot       91.6G   796G  3.15K  4.66K   220M   399M
zroot       91.6G   796G  2.65K      0   150M      0
zroot       91.4G   797G  3.66K  4.39K   202M   381M

all the zeroes in read and write columns worry me. On old server there are no zeroes and copy speed is consistent, but this new server reaches  189M read speed while the old server is consistent at around 80M. It seems like on the new server reads saturate writes. Is there any setting of zfs (I have default) that I could change to improve this? The disk is some nvme SSD at ovh, a single drive zfs

No, writes on new server are faster than the reads and so there is no requirements all-the-time between the zfs write transactions. Your problem is on the "read" side while you cp.
